# Missed Zoltan card from White Orchard scholar

Tags: the-witcher-3

I somehow missed the Zoltan card from beating the scholar at White Orchard Inn, is there any way that I can get another opportunity at the card?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From 1.07 patch note fix.

The Zoltan gwent card should now always be present beneath the Hanged Man's Tree if the player does not win it earlier in White Orchard.